# How can I revalue elements in factor based on values of arguments, passed to the function in R?

Tags: r, function, replace, parameter-passing, plyr

I have a function to which I pass certain values that are levels in a factor. I would like to revalue levels in factor, based on this values.

For example, if I want to revalue levels in factor `my_factor` ("cats" -> "animals", "pines" -> "trees"), I use:
`my_factor <- revalue(my_factor, c("cats"="animals", "pines"="trees"))`. **But now I want to revalue levels, based on values of arguments, passed to the function**:

```
myFunction(..., member1 = "cats", member2 = "pines") {
my_factor <- revalue(my_factor, c(member1="animals", member2="trees"))
}
```

This fragment of code isn't working (`Error: The following` from`values were not present in`x`: member1, member2`).

Please tell me how to do it correctly?
Perhaps I need to use something other than `revalue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference `plyr`, but that package is "retired" and its use is generally not recommended. I'm not going to attempt a solution in the `dplyr` manner, since I don't have a sufficient command of it's various levels of abstraction.

The base function `levels<-` will do this cleanly. When you do something like:

```
levels(fac)[some_index] <- "something"
```

You change the print value of that level without changing the underlying pattern of factor integers that carry the information. So use `levels(fac)`; once to get the current values of the levels to create a logical index to use inside "[" , and again on the "outside" of the LHS to do the reassignment:

```
levels(fac)[ levels(fac) == "cats"] <- "animals"
levels(fac)[ levels(fac) == "pines"] <- "trees"
```

You are actually using two different functions: `levels<-` (on the outside) and `levels` (on the inside). To make this process into a function that can handle an arbitrary number of reassignments, you would want the reassignment pairs to be carried in a list of lists so you could iterate over the pairs. Your current request is attempting to use a language-like expression such as `"cats" = "animals"`, but that would create a parameter named `cats` with a value of `"animals"`. Looking at the code of `plyr::revalue` I can see that it then needs to undo that construction before it sends the names and values to `mapvalues` which works with two separate sets of parameters. At any rate, here's an old-school attempt.

```
reval <- function(x)(fac, reassigns) {
             levs <-lapply(reassigns, function(fac, pair) {
                       levels(fac)[levels(fac)==pair[[1]]] <-pair[[2]]}
                                      return(levs) }
```

And you would call it like this:

```
levels(facname) <- reval ( facname, list( list("curlev1", "newlev1"),
                                  list("curlev2", "newlev2")) )  )
```

If you have an example off the example naming you used "my_factor ("cats" -> "animals", "pines" -> "trees")" then test it with

```
levels(my_factor)<- reval(my_factor, reassigns = list (list("cats" , "animals"),
                                           list("pines", "trees") ) )
```

If it doesn't work, then you should post R code to create an example that can be used for further development and testing. And looking at the `dplyr` Index, I see the `recode` function which has a factor method. This is the example from that help page that appears to match your desires:

```
# For factor values, use only named replacements
# and supply default with levels()
factor_vec <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
recode(factor_vec, a = "Apple", .default = levels(factor_vec))
```

**As (almost) always**, R will not actually modify `factor_vec` unless you assign the result of recode back to the original name

```
factor_vec <- recode(factor_vec, a = "Apple", .default = levels(factor_vec))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer, 
I added `pair` to your function, since R indicated that it was not set.
`reval <- function(fac, reassigns) {
    for (i in 1:length(reassigns)) {
        pair <- reassigns[[i]]
        levs <-lapply(reassigns, function(fac, pair) {          
            levels(fac)[levels(fac)==pair[[1]]] <-pair[[2]]})
                                      return(levs) }
    }`

 But it causes the same error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): argument "pair" is missing, with no default`. Could you help with the modification, please?

Comment: `my_factor <- factor(c("cats", "cats", "pines"))`

`curlev1 <- "cats"`

`curlev2 <- "pines"`

`reval(my_factor, reassigns = list (list(curlev1 , "animals"), list(curlev2 , "trees") )  )`

Comment: As for using `recode` from `dplyr`, it seems to me that this is not really my case, since I want to set curlev in advance.
`factor_vec <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))

name <- "a"

recode(factor_vec, name = "Apple", .default = levels(factor_vec))`

'factor_vec' remains the same (`"a", "b", "c"`).

Comment: But I think, that I can use solution method  in a simpler version:
`reval_simple <- function(my_factor, curlev1, curlev2) {
    levels(my_factor)[levels(my_factor) == curlev1] <- "animals"
    levels(my_factor)[levels(my_factor) ==curlev2] <- "trees"
    return(my_factor)
}`

And then:
`some_my_factor <- factor(c("cats", "cats", "pines"))
some_curlev1 <- "cats"
some_curlev2 <- "pines"

reval_simple(some_my_factor, some_curlev1, some_curlev2)`

Comment: Read the last bit again: `recode(factor_vec, name = "Apple", .default = levels(factor_vec))` will have no lasting effect, but `factor_vec <- recode(factor_vec, name = "Apple", .default = levels(factor_vec))` just might succeed.